# R - How to get matrix from multidimensional array

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, sub-array

Suppose I've got 5D array `arr`.
To get 2d matrix with fixed 3rd, 4th and 5th indices I do something like: `matr = arr[,,3,2,3]`. Suppose I've got list of indices `idx = c(3,2,3)`. Is there any way to get same result using `idx`? Something like `matr = arr[,,idx]`? I've tried to do it like

```
idx = c(,, 3, 2, 3);
matr = arr[idx];
```

But it is obviously wrong.

**UPD** in a common case array may be more than 5 dimensional. So  I need to do this for idx of any size.

Comment: Does `idx` always indicates the 3rd, 4th and 5th dimension?

Comment: If the array is more than 5D, then it is 3rd, 4th, 5th, ..., Nth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
do.call("[",c(list(arr,TRUE,TRUE),as.list(idx)))
```

An example on some data:

```
set.seed(123)
arraydims<-c(5, 3, 6, 3, 4)
arr<-array(runif(prod(arraydims)),arraydims)
idx<-c(2,3,2)
identical(arr[,,2,3,2],do.call("[",c(list(arr,TRUE,TRUE),as.list(idx))))
#[1] TRUE
```

You can also exploit the [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) used by R:

```
array(arr[sum(c(1,cumprod(dim(arr)))[3:length(dim(arr))]*(idx-1))+
            seq_len(prod(dim(arr)[1:2]))],dim(arr)[1:2])
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this one, but I am also sure there should be something more adequate...

```
A <- array(1:72, dim=c(2,2,3,2,2))
res <- eval(parse(text=paste0("A[,,",paste0(idx,collapse=",")),"]")))
```

Basically prepare your indexing as string. Opportunity to create a function there.

Comment: Yeah, I got the idea. I thought about something like this before, but I'm very new in R, so didn't know there is `eval` in R. Sadly, but I thing eval is the only way:( UPD: nicola proposed more adequate solution. But thank you anyway.